# Hiding the decimal if .0 and showing zero if an integer

Tags: php, mysql

I have two, hopefully basic number questions.

First, I am using the decimal data type on MySQL to show data like speed or height set to one decimal place like this `decimal(4,1)` My problem is that for numbers with no dp it is still showing .0 - What I get is '309.0' but what I want is '309'. What do I need to change to hide the '.0'?

Second I have an integer data type showing fixed numbers. Many of the numbers are 0 zero but these are getting treated as null and not displaying. How do I force the 0's to display? (I can't make table changes for this because other columns do have zero's that are null values. It is only this one column that needs zeros to display).

For both of these problems PHP is being used to display the results.

EDIT: code I'm using to display results. the top one needs to not show .0 the bottom one needs to show a zero.

```
Length:</b> %sft' . PHP_EOL, $row2['length'])

Inversions:</b> %s' . PHP_EOL, $row2['inversions'])
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to display the DB results?

Comment: @MikeBrant Ive edited to show the display code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a sneaky trick is if you add 0 to the end of your number, it removes the .0000 etc.

example:

```
$number = 150.00
$number = $number + 0; //should echo 150
$other_number = 150.500;
$other_number += 0; //should echo 150.5
```

As for the other, you can simply concatenate the zeros since no calculations seem to be needed

Comment: I don't know how 'proper' this method is but it seems to have worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To check for the trailing zero, you could use the following to make sure that the float and integer values are the same:

```
$num = (floatval($num)==intval($num)) ? intval($num) : floatval($num);
```

and then for the null value, you could use `coalesce(yourColumn, 0) as yourColumn` to either get your column value if not null or return 0 as the value..

Comment: Turns out the zero's do display the issue is I am using this code `if(!empty($row2['inversions'])){` and even with your above method it treats it as null so doesn't show anything. If I remove the if statement the Zero shows. Would you know how I could alter this?